# Python: issue in adding elements to a list

Tags: python, list

I have a small problem in adding the results printed by a function to a list. The situation is like this. The function prints some results like this

```
result1
result2
result3
```

How do I add them into a list, to see them like `mylist=['result1', 'result2', 'result3']`? Because, in my case, I am working with a for loop which calculates every case using the function written by me (and prints the results like above) but using append function, it prints something like this:

```
 ['result1'], ['result1', 'result2'], ['result1', 'result2', 'result3'].
```

Of course, using the last result, `['result1', 'result2', 'result3']`, should be perfect for me, but I am getting three lists like above. What ca I do to have only the last list, the one with those three results?

Ok guys, I'm gonna put some code here to be more specific. I have a large string (and I'm not gonna write it here because is not so important). My function is splitting from that string some specific url's. The function is this:

```
def fileref(string, file):
    start=string.find(file) + 28
    end=string.find('</ref', start)
    file=string[start:end]
    return file
```

I have this list with arguments for the function:

```
files55_2=['f55_1.jpg', 'f55_2.jpg', 'f55_3.txt', 'f55_4.mp4']
```

Then, with a for loop I do this:

```
for i in files55_2:
    print fileref(string, i)
```

which prints me these urls:

```
https://myapi.net/file1
https://myapi.net/file2
https://myapi.net/file3
https://myapi.net/file4
```

Now I need a solution to have a list with all these elements, like this:

```
mylist=['https://myapi.net/file1', 'https://myapi.net/file2', 'https://myapi.net/file3', 'https://myapi.net/file4']
```

I hope I am more specific now. Thanks anyway for your answers!

Comment: Could you give an example of the function you are working wiht? Also it might help to add a few gaps in this ;) EDIT - someone's already put gaps in

Comment: Are you printing in loop an the incremental list that gets printed gives you feeling like having three lists? Or, you actually get three List objects? Code please.

Comment: I don't think anyone can understand the problem the way you stated it. At most someone can do is guess your problem. Please add at least some code snippets from you function and from the code where you are using it, with input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off having your function append the results to the list, then printing outside the function.

```
>>> def append():
...   l = []
...   for i in range(3):
...     l.append(str(i))
...   return l
...
>>> l = append()
>>> l
['0', '1', '2']
```

Or if you already have the list before running the function, you won't need to return it.

```
>>> def append(l):
...   for i in range(3):
...     l.append(str(i))
...
>>> l = []
>>> append(l)
>>> l
['0', '1', '2']
```

Comment: @BioGeek: I tried this before posting the question and it shows me the same incrementation of the lists.

Answer (score 5):

In your function you are incrementally building your list and printing out the list after every step, something like this:

```
l = []
for i in range(1,4):
    l.append("result {0}".format(i))
    print l
```

output:

```
['result 1']
['result 1', 'result 2']
['result 1', 'result 2', 'result 3']
```

What you want to do is to print out the list after you are done creating it, something like:

```
l = []
for i in range(1,4):
    l.append("result {0}".format(i))
print l
```

output:

```
['result 1', 'result 2', 'result 3']
```

**edit:**  In the provided code, change these lines:

```
for i in files55_2:
    print fileref(string, i)
```

to:

```
mylist = []
for i in files55_2:
    mylist.append(fileref(string, i))
print mylist
```

Answer (score 1):

In for loop you can use "else" close, which executes after loop has finished:

```
for ...
   ...
else
   //here you can add your results to list after loop has finished
```